# C#: Reading HTML from a website

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, webclient

I'm trying to read a website (https://www.megaplextheatres.com/geneva).  I want to read the website so that I can get a notification when it updates.  I'm just trying to get good seats at the movies haha :)

I've started reading with a webclient and an httpwebrequest.  When I read the data, I don't get ALL the data.  I need to get the "buttons" that show the dates of the movies.

Here's what I have so far:

```
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            response.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Comment: [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) is your friend

Answer (score 0):

as per suggested by @mohitshrivastava

```
WebElement td_appname = driver.findElement.ByLinkText("MindMeister - 251-500 Pupil License");
WebElement td_appdescription = td_appname.findElement.Byxpath("./../td[2]");
String appdescription = td_appdescription.getText();
```

I hope it helps